# Animated Three.js file not rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have made an animation in Blender and I exported it as a Three.js file so that I could display it in my Three.js code.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "obj/dog5.js", function( geometry ) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
    mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
    mesh.position.y = 20;
    mesh.position.x = 0;

    var materials = mesh.material.materials;

    for (var k in materials) {
        materials[k].skinning = true;
    }

    animation = new THREE.Animation(mesh, "ArmatureAction", THREE.AnimationHandler.CATMULLROM);
    animation.play();

    lesson6.scene.add(mesh);
```

This is the error I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is where it happens in my code:

```
animation = new THREE.Animation(mesh, "ArmatureAction", THREE.AnimationHandler.CATMULLROM);
```

This is where it happens in the Three.js library file three.min.js:

```
init:function(a){if(!0===a.initialized)return a;for(var b=0;b<a.hierarchy.length;b++)
```

I know my JSON file has a hierarchy so I don't know why it's undefined. I'm thinking I'm just missing some code, I'm not sure.

If I take away the animation stuff the regular object renders but doesn't animate.

I'm completely stumped. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT:**

So it's rendering now with this code:

```
          for ( var k in materials ) {

        materials[k].skinning = true;

      }

      skinnedMesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
      skinnedMesh.scale.set( 11, 11, 11 );
      lesson6.scene.add( skinnedMesh );
      animation = new THREE.Animation( skinnedMesh, skinnedMesh.geometry.animations[ 0 ], THREE.AnimationHandler.CATMULLROM);
      animation.play();
```

But it still doesn't animate. Do I need a start time with animation.play? Could it possibly be my json?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Use the non-minified version of three.js for debugging. (2) Use the most recent version of three.js. (3) Learn from the three.js examples: e.g., http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_skinning_simple.html.

Comment: Thanks for advice! I've tried that sample code and other sample code before and for some reason I can always get it to render but never animate. Could it possibly be my json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I was animating and rendering incorrectly.

Solution from [threejs.org/examples/webgl_skinning_simple.html](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_skinning_simple.html):

```
function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  THREE.AnimationHandler.update( clock.getDelta() );

  controls.update();

  render();
  stats.update();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```